# The performance of (++) with lazy evaluation

Tags: haskell, concatenation, lazy-evaluation

I have been wondering about this a lot, and I haven't found satisfying answers.

Why is `(++)` "expensive"? Under lazy evaluation, we won't evaluate an expression like

```
xs ++ ys
```

before necessary, and even then, we will only evaluate the part we need, *when* we need them.

Can someone explain what I'm missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you access the whole resulting list, lazy evaluation won't save any computation. It will only delay it until you need each particular element, but at the end, you have to compute the same thing.

If you traverse the concatenated list `xs ++ ys`, accessing each element of the first part (`xs`) adds a little constant overhead, checking if `xs` was spent or not.

So, it makes a big difference if you associate `++` to the left or to the right.

- If you associate `n` lists of length `k` to the **left** like `(..(xs1 ++ xs2) ... ) ++ xsn` then accessing each of the first `k` elements will take `O(n)` time, accessing each of the next `k` ones will take `O(n-1)` etc. So traversing the whole list will take `O(k n^2)`. You can check that

  ```
  sum $ foldl (++) [] (replicate 100000 [1])
  ```

  takes *really* long.
- If you associate `n` lists of length `k` to the **right** like `xs1 ++ ( ..(xsn_1 ++ xsn) .. )` then you'll get only constant overhead for each element, so traversing the whole list will be only `O(k n)`. You can check that

  ```
  sum $ foldr (++) [] (replicate 100000 [1])
  ```

  is quite reasonable.

---

**Edit:** This is just the magic hidden behind `ShowS`. If you convert each string `xs` to  `showString xs :: String -> String` (`showString` is just an alias for `(++)`) and compose these functions, then no matter how you associate their composition, at the end they will be applied from right to left - just what we need to get the linear time complexity. (This is simply because `(f . g) x` is `f (g x)`.)

You can check that both

```
length $ (foldl (.) id (replicate 1000000 (showString "x"))) ""
```

and

```
length $ (foldr (.) id (replicate 1000000 (showString "x"))) ""
```

run in a reasonable time (`foldr` is a bit faster because it has less overhead when composing functions from the right, but both are linear in the number of elements).

Comment: (Do you mean `foldr` for the second one?)

Answer (score 5):

It's not too expensive on its own, the problem arises when you start combining a whole lot of `++` from *left to right*: such a chain is evaluated like

```
  ( ([1,2] ++ [3,4]) ++ [5,6] ) ++ [7,8]
≡ let a = ([1,2] ++ [3,4]) ++ [5,6]
        ≡ let b = [1,2] ++ [3,4]
                ≡ let c = [1,2]
                  in  head c : tail c ++ [3,4]
                    ≡ 1 : [2] ++ [3,4]
                    ≡ 1 : 2 : [] ++ [3,4]
                    ≡ 1 : 2 : [3,4]
                    ≡ [1,2,3,4]
          in  head b : tail b ++ [5,6]
            ≡ 1 : [2,3,4] ++ [5,6]
            ≡ 1:2 : [3,4] ++ [5,6]
            ≡ 1:2:3 : [4] ++ [5,6]
            ≡ 1:2:3:4 : [] ++ [5,6]
            ≡ 1:2:3:4:[5,6]
            ≡ [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  in head a : tail a ++ [7,8]
   ≡ 1 : [2,3,4,5,6] ++ [7,8]
   ≡ 1:2 : [3,4,5,6] ++ [7,8]
   ≡ 1:2:3 : [4,5,6] ++ [7,8]
   ≡ 1:2:3:4 : [5,6] ++ [7,8]
   ≡ 1:2:3:4:5 : [6] ++ [7,8]
   ≡ 1:2:3:4:5:6 : [] ++ [7,8]
   ≡ 1:2:3:4:5:6 : [7,8]
   ≡ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

where you clearly see the quadratic complexity. Even if you only want to evaluate up to the *n*-th element, you still have to dig your way through *all* those `let`s. That's why `++` is `infixr`, for `[1,2] ++ ( [3,4] ++ ([5,6] ++ [7,8]) )` is actually much more efficient. But if you're not careful while designing, say, a simple serialiser, you may easily end up with a chain like the one above. This is the main reason why beginners are warned about `++`.

That aside, `Prelude.++` is slow compared to e.g. `Bytestring` operations for the simple reason that it works by traversing linked lists, which have always suboptimal cache usage etc., but that's not as problematic; this prevents you from achieving C-like performance but properly written programs using only plain lists and `++` can still easily rival similar programs written in e.g. Python.

Comment: [That's not how `(++)` is defined...](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Base.html#%2B%2B) (And I'm not sure they are directly equivalent...)

Comment: @dbaupp: I know, but it was better writable this way here. And yes, I'm pretty sure they're directly equivalent, in fact isn't this exactly the rewrite rule they use?

Comment: Actually... no, the `"foldr/app"` rule towards the top of the file rewrites the `foldr` version back to the `x : (xs ++ ys)` version. The `"++"` rule is to facilitate list fusion.

Comment: I see. Well that's a bit roundabout, isn't it? But these rewrite rules are certainly one of the resons Haskell lists are so fast. Anyway, doesn't the model explanation still fit? The complexity is certainly right, I'm not sure about the lazy evaluation behaviour right now...

Comment: Yeah it is! I'm sure its a bit of a maintainence headache! (I'm not sure the analysis of the complexity is right, because as you've written it, it is O(n) to retrieve the first element, while the definition is O(1).)

Comment: It can't possibly be _O_ (1), because to get to the first element all _n_ `++`'s need to be evaluated at least to weak head normal form. Regardless of how `++` is implemented, this must be at least _O_ (_n_). — Rewrote the example without `foldr` now, doesn't look too different, but I'm not sure if it's quite correct this way (with the implied pattern matching at each step).

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding, I was referring to the complexity of an access to the head of a single append (so the n is the length of the first list), since you appeared to use an accumulation parameter. (However, `head $ foldr (:) [] [1..]` terminates, so that is clearly not true, apparently I misunderstood your previous explanation.)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add one thing or two to Petr's answer.

As he pointed out, repeatedly appending lists at the beginning is quite cheap, while appending to the bottom is not. This is true as long as you use haskell's lists.
However, there are certain circumstances in which you HAVE TO append to the end (e.g., you are building a string to be printed out). With regular lists you have to deal with the quadratic complexity mentioned by his answer, but there's a way better solution in these cases: [difference lists](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/data-structures.html#data.dlist) (see also [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329660/efficient-list-append-prepend-through-function-composition) on the topic).

Long story short, by describing lists as compositions of functions instead of concatenation of shorter lists you are able to append lists or individual elements at the beginning or at the end of your difference list by composing functions, in constant time. Once you're done, you can extract a regular list in linear time (in the number of elements).